# What can magic in D&D 5e not do?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am currently running a campaign that is very Forgotten Realms-esque.  Lots of magic, moderate amounts of magic items, and lots of magical creatures... Also, access to all the different planes of existence. ... And, of course, the Wish spell and the limitations that come with that spell.

One of the biggest limitations with the Wish spell is that if you try to do anything other than duplicate a 8th or lower spell, then you run the risk of not being able to cast it again.

Given that pretext, what is something that all of those things together cannot accomplish?  I ask because the crux of my PC's main quest is dependent on a magic item that can do something that can't be done otherwise within the RAR or RAI.

The immediate example(in the real world) is the Philosopher's Stone.  This mystical item can turn any object into gold.

Comment: I think you're mixing up the Philosopher's Stone and Midas' Hand... turning *other metals* to gold is one one aspect of a Philosopher's Stone, but not even it's most well-known use. Midas' Hand turns any object touched to solid gold.

Comment: Krchlt, how is your world populated with classed-leveled individuals? In my games, I had the percentage of the population with the ability to reach a given level was something like Level!/(Level^ProficiencyBonus), where ! is factorial operation. As a result, with a population of 1 Billion you would expect about 3 individuals with the capability to reach level 17 in any class, and not all individuals reach their full capability, nor select a full casting class. Such individuals would be rare. Wish may simply not be available (especially if the able user "burned out" previously).

Comment: After thinking for a few hours, I couldn't figure out how to reword this  question to fall within the guidelines of asking a question. Ifusaso correct.  I meant to clarify that the philosopher's stone could turn metals into gold. sharur, that is a good point.  My world only has like 7 people that could get to 17+.  So that is interesting.